# Disable window grouping in Dock on Ubuntu 17.10/18.04

Tags: gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock

In the gnome-based desktop, which was introduced with Ubuntu 17.10, is it possible to have one button for each window in the dock instead of having them grouped by application?

For example, if I have two Firefox windows open I would like to have two Firefox buttons.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As a specific answer to your question, no, you cannot do that with Ubuntu Dock. You can also not achieve that with the extension [Dash to Dock](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/307/dash-to-dock/), on which Ubuntu Dock is based. Despite the fact that installing Dash to Dock exposes you to a lot of settings, there is no option to have the Dock display separate icons for separate applications.

If you are willing to abandon a dock, but instead have your icons on the panel, then the [Dash to Panel](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1160/dash-to-panel/) extension can be configured to show one icon for each Window; setting: *Behavior* > "*Ungroup Applications*" as shown below:

[image]

In addition, it can be configured to also show the window title, and at that moment looks and behaves as a traditional task bar.

Comment: It took some time for me to test this, but it doesn't seem to be possible to configure Dash to Panel to show one icon for each window - at least not with the current version. Edit: Nevermin, the setting is called "ungroup Applications".

Comment: For people new to gnome extensions, navigate to https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1160/dash-to-panel/ in FireFox (Chrome doesn't work) and install from webpage. You might also need to run `sudo apt install gnome-shell-extensions`.